# How to define a template url when using a component

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am using a knockout component but I want to use a template url instead of an inline template. Here is the component I am using:

```
ko.components.register('cat-data', {
    viewModel: {
        createViewModel: function(params, componentInfo) {
            var self = this;

            self.data = (params && params.data) || [];

            return self;
        }
    },
    template: "/Scripts/CatdDataTemplate.html"
});
```

When I run this `/Scripts/CatdDataTemplate.html` is displayed and not the actual template.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The template property as a string will be parsed by knockout as the actual template to apply. If you want to load a template from a url, you can do so using a custom loader, as defined in the [knockout documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-loaders.html#example-2-a-component-loader-that-loads-external-files-using-custom-code), quoted below:

> If your custom loader implements loadTemplate and/or loadViewModel,
>   then you can plug in custom code to the loading process. You can also
>   use these functions to interpret custom configuration formats.
>
> For example, you might want to enable configuration formats like the
>   following:

```
ko.components.register('my-component', {
    template: { fromUrl: 'file.html', maxCacheAge: 1234 },
    viewModel: { viaLoader: '/path/myvm.js' } 
});
```

> … and you can do so using custom loaders.
>
> The following custom loader will take care of loading templates
>   configured with a fromUrl value:

```
var templateFromUrlLoader = {
    loadTemplate: function(name, templateConfig, callback) {
        if (templateConfig.fromUrl) {
            // Uses jQuery's ajax facility to load the markup from a file
            var fullUrl = '/templates/' + templateConfig.fromUrl + '?cacheAge=' + templateConfig.maxCacheAge;
            $.get(fullUrl, function(markupString) {
                // We need an array of DOM nodes, not a string.
                // We can use the default loader to convert to the
                // required format.
                ko.components.defaultLoader.loadTemplate(name, markupString, callback);
            });
        } else {
            // Unrecognized config format. Let another loader handle it.
            callback(null);
        }
    } };   // Register it ko.components.loaders.unshift(templateFromUrlLoader);
```

Source: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-loaders.html#example-2-a-component-loader-that-loads-external-files-using-custom-code